# Run combination of methods based on user input?

Tags: java

Assuming I have 4 methods

```
methodA() 
methodB()
methodC()
methodD()
```

Now I want the user to be able to input a number to run a combination of the methods.

So the user can choose if they want to run:
methodA() and methodB()

or:
methodB(), methodC() and methodD()

or just one of the methods or all of them.

Is there any other possibility than specifying any possible combination in if-statements?

Comment: you could use `YourClass.getDeclaredMethods()` and then execute the ones the user selected

Comment: Enter a string "BCAD" and run the corresponding method for each caracter ?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by " Enter a string "BCAD" and run the corresponding method for each character".

Comment: There is a lot of possibilities based on what you want. Do you have a specific set of method or is it dynamic ? Is it always without parameters ? What is the return value (if any) ? ...

Comment: Is this a command line program? I use commons-cli and declare options. The user can then use for example --methodA --methodB to specify which ones to run. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/

Comment: Are you going to have a GUI? If yes, you could present the methods in a ListView.

Comment: the methods get a parameter (List<String>).  The 4 methods are different Named Entity Recognition APIs, and the user should be able to choose if he wants to get the extracted topics only from 1 API or from a combination of 2 of them or 3 of them or all 4. The return value then is the topic and the topic count, how often do the topics appear in the text, and it is a command line porgram

Comment: Then this is really to broad... you need to [edit] your question to include a complete example of what you want to do.

Comment: well if I would know how to do it I would not ask. Should i change my question to all combinations in if statements and ask again if there is another possibility then if-statements?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a bitmask.  In that way one number could represent multiple flags that indicate which methods get called.  A quick google search returned the following:

http://drumcoder.co.uk/blog/2010/jan/06/bitmasks-java/ Explains some solutions for this problem, which is what I think you're facing.

> If you need to store multiple boolean flags for something, you can do
>   it using bits and storing that inside a single integer.

Comment: You should add more information, include what is relevant in the link. See [answer] about links. I see this as a comment for the moment.